# Application of Convolution Formula

Tags: statistics

I got the following from my statistics lecture today.

Can someone explain to me the last 2 steps?
Specifically, how $f_Y(t-x)=1$

Thanks!

[image]

**Edit 1:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f_Y(y)$ is the pdf of the uniform distribution, hence,
$$
f_Y(y) = \mathbb{I}_{(0 \le y \le 1)}
$$
and in your case you are looking at $f_Y(t-x)$, which is $1$ whenever $0 \le t-x \le 1$ and zero otherwise.

The first case inequality implies $x \le t \le 1+x$.

Comment: Hmmm okay so given $0 \lt t \lt 1$, how do we know $x \le t \le1+x$?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus this is what your text is using -- $f_Y(t-x)=0$ when $t-x<0$ (equivalently, $x>t$) and $0<t<1$, so you only need to integrate to $t$ to have non-zero contributions, and when you do, $f_Y(t-x)=1$ everywhere on the interval of integration.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it, see **Edit 1**